# How to solve dependency problem in maven because of using different versions of same project

Tags: java, maven

I have 4 modules in my project. 
Module1 (i.e. com.assign.print:printlog.value:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT) has one class i.e. Foo.java, inside this class, on more class is there which is using com.print.assess: mns.pro:2.0

Module2 , Module2 and Module4 are using com.print.assess: mns.pro:6.2.

In my project main pom.xml, the dependency is added as :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.print.assess</groupId>
   <artifactId>mns.pro</artifaxtId>
   <version>6.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

In Foo.java, I have one class as DataVal.java which is using older version.
If I don't add

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.print.assess</groupId>
   <artifactId>mns.pro</artifaxtId>
   <version>2.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

to Module1 pom.xml, Redline error is coming for DataVal.java saying "cannot resolve the symbol". So when I added the dependency with version 2.0, the error was resolved but while installing project:

```
Failed while enforcing releasability the error(s) are [
Dependency convergence error for com.print.assess:mns.pro:6.2 paths to 
dependency are:


+-com.assign.print:printlog.value:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.app.print:print.sal:1.1.3
   +-com.print.assess:mns.pro:6.2
and
+-com.assign.print:printlog.value:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.print.assess:mns.pro:2.0
and
+-com.assign.print:printlog.value:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-com.print.assess.over:multi-task.rev:3.1
    +-com.print.assess:mns.pro:6.2
```

How to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the dependencyConvergence enforcer rule active (which you obviously have), you need to determine your versions in the `<dependencyManagement>` (which is different from the standard `<dependencies>`).

Then you can declare the dependencies without version in `<dependencies>`. dependencyManagement entries can be in the main pom and in modules as well. @Bahmut gave you the link to understand dependencyManagement.

Comment: The problem is in the same module. Module1 has multiple classes. Among those multiple classes, one of the class is using different version of ProjectA. What should I do with that?

Comment: One module can only have one version of a dependency (although there are ways around this with the maven shade plugin, but I never used that).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to move your 6.2 dependency in your main pom to `<dependencyManagement>` so it does not get imported by default. Then you can simply import the 6.2 version in your module poms like this:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.print.assess</groupId>
   <artifactId>mns.pro</artifaxtId>
 </dependency>
```

and in the module where you need version 2, you can import it like this:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.print.assess</groupId>
   <artifactId>mns.pro</artifaxtId>
   <version>2.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

More information about dependency management can be found here:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: I have 6.2 dependency in main pom and 2.0 dependency in module1 pom. but its failing while build.